# what is the name " : " operator in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have faced this Question twice in different interviews and still not getting satisfied answer from internet any one have idea? ..

the question is 
     what is the name of the operator in c# which is used for Inheritance?

Comment: It's *not* an operator (see the complete list of C# operators at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx)

Comment: there is no such operator

Comment: It does not have a name, the few places where it is referred to as an operator it is referred to as "the `:` operator", example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228387(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Next time reverse the question to interviewer. As far as i know it is not an operator. May be they are asking about symbol

Comment: The closest you come to an operator is the `?:` (ternary operator). Otherwise its just syntax

Comment: Its not an operator. Its a syntax to use inheritance. e.g. childClass:baseClass

Comment: [C# basics Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/) guess you should understand coding before going into the interview.. you should know this if you are indeed a C# coder

Comment: @methodMan Unfortunately i got job and Working as mvc developer  if u know the answer of my question then plz answer me..

Comment: I'm amazed someone would consider this meaningless piece of trivia a worthy interview question.

Answer (score 8):

This "operator" does not have a name, and it is also a question whether it is really considered an operator in the first place.

If you take a look at the [official list of C# operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) you will not find it, which would suggest that Microsoft doesn't count it as an operator.

However, if you look into official documentation and information written on class inheritance and interface implementation you will find it being referred to as "the `:` operator", which *does* suggest Microsoft at least thinks of it as sort of an operator.

You can find an example of the latter here: [Inheritance and Derived Classes (C# vs. Java)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228387(v=vs.90).aspx):

> In C#, both inheritance and interface implementation are defined by the `:` **operator**, equivalent to extends and implements in Java. The base class should always be leftmost in the class declaration.

*(my emphasis)*

I have never seen it with a different name, however, so it may be that the interviewers are coming from a Java world, or have seen Java names for it, where it has a more official name.

Note that the term *operator* is usually reserved for a symbol which involves an operation, used together with operands which are parameters to said operation. None of this is applicable to a class declaration, this is just a symbol used to denote different parts of the syntax for the declaration.

Comment: The best thing to do in your situation would've been to actually just ask the interviewers. If they withhold the correct (if only in their mind) information after the interview is over, I wouldn't want to work there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It requires to clarify the terminology. Operators are constructions, which occur in expressions, and which have operands and a result.

F.e., there is the [comma operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs06xbxh.aspx), which provides a sequential calculation of expressions, and has the result that equals to result of the last expression.

But the same comma in other contexts is not an operator, but a delimiter.

With regard to the colon in the context of inheritance, it's not an operator nor a delimiter, it's syntax construct that has not separate name.

Answer (score 0):

In c#, `:` operator is used with `?` when one has to use shorthand of `if else` It is called ternary operator
For example,

```
int i = 0;
if(isSomething == true)
{
i = 1
}
else if(isSomething == false)
{
i = 2
}
```

or one can use instead:

```
i = isSomething == true ? 1 : 2
```

The Double `:` Operator `::` is also used to access The namespace alias qualifier. It is always positioned between two identifiers, as in this example:

```
global::System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
```

Comment: this situation An example of Misc Operators which refer to Conditional Expression ? : .I, Asking about this...  SimpleController : Controller